# Detect file add/remove in node/webpack project

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I am working on a webpack project where some types of objects should register themselves into a 'Registry' to be accessible easily through the project.

To be more accurate, the project structure looks like this example:

```
- src
+- registry
 +- ServiceRegistry.js
+- services
 +- index.js
 +- Service1.js
+ index.js
```

src/services/index.js - this file is in charge to import all the Services

```
import 'services/Service1'
```

src/services/Service1.js - the Service register itself to the ServiceRegistry

```
import ServiceRegistry from 'registry/ServiceRegistry'
const Service1 = { /* blablabla */ }
ServiceRegistry.register('Service1', Service1)
```

src/index.js - the service index is imported at top level to make sure all Services will be loaded

```
import 'services'
```

Every time one adds a new 'Service' it must be referenced in src/service/index.js. This might sound easy but its actually a regular waste of time when forgotten + there are more than one type of object following this pattern.

What I would like to achieve is to regenerate the src/services/index.js file each time a .js is created or deleted in the src/services folder.

Some googling did not bring an obvious solution :(

Any help appreciated, thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [babel-plugin-wildcard](https://github.com/vihanb/babel-plugin-wildcard) ?

From the documentation example looks exactly what you are looking for:

> https://github.com/vihanb/babel-plugin-wildcard#example

**Edit: pasting the example from above link reference**

#### Example

With the following folder structure:

```
|- index.js
|- dir
    |- a.js
    |- b.js
    |- c.js
```

the following JS:

```
import * as Items from './dir';
```

will be compiled to:

```
const Items = {};
import _wcImport from "./dir/a";
Items.A = _wcImport;
import _wcImport1 from "./dir/b";
Items.B = _wcImport1;
import _wcImport2 from "./dir/c";
Items.C = _wcImport2;
```

meaning you will be able to access the items using `Items.A` and `Items.B`.

Comment: Hi, this plugin was missing the 'recursive' feature but you put me on the good track with a babel plugin and I was able to get rid of my index.js files with babel-plugin-import-directory :) (https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-import-directory)